# Laravel validation of datetime using old()

Tags: forms, validation, laravel-8

I have an edit form I need verified with several datetime inputs.

Here is an example of one of the inputs. Can `old()` be used this way?

```
<input 
type="text" 
name="call_timeRecd" 
id="call_timeRecd"
class="form-control 
form-control-sm"
value="{{ $data->call_timeRecd ? date('Y-m-d H:i', (new DateTime( old($data->call_timeRecd, $data->call_timeRecd) ))->getTimestamp()) : '' }}" />
```

I'm trying to have invalid inputs return to the form with an error and the invalid input displayed in the input box. However, it is showing the original input rather than the incorrect version when it returns with the error.

`$data` is a MySql record and `call_timeRecd` is a timestamp field.

Comment: I don't follow what your code is doing (what are the 2x `>`?), but [`old()` takes a field *name*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#repopulating-forms), not a value.  In your case that would be `old('call_timeRecd', ...)`.

Comment: Also I think you are talking about *validation*?  While that is a kind of verification, the term is probably misleading here, and if you are talking about validation I'd suggest editing your question and removing/updating that tag and terminology.

Comment: Some extra characters got introduced in the code. Not sure why. I've deleted them now. You're right, I did mean validation. And your first comment fixed the problem, thanks! If anyone else lands on this question, the corrected code in the value part is: ```{{ $data->call_timeRecd ? old('call_timeRecd', date('Y-m-d H:i', (new DateTime( $data->call_timeRecd ))->getTimestamp())) : '' }}```